# Rails: Updating existing record with information from nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes

I have nested attributes under my user's view and would like to update an existing record information in my business table, but when I save value in the nested attribute its just adding a new record.

I have this in my view

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :businesses do |biz| %>
    <%= biz.text_field :street %>
    <%= biz.text_field :city %>
    <%= biz.text_field :zip %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then I have this in my controller:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  @user.businesses.new if @user.businesses.empty?
end 

def update
  @biz = Business.find_or_create_by_name(params[:user][:company_name])
end
```

So the update method allows the "company_name" (that's NOT in the nested attribute) to be saved in the **Business** table in addition to the **Users** table. But now I'd like to get the street, city, and zip, that is the nested attribute, be saved in business record with the `company_name's` record.

I think I have to get the business id and then update the record based on that id, not sure how?

Can I do something like

```
def update
  @biz = Business.find_or_create_by_name(params[:user][:company_name])
  @biz.id #to get the id of the business when updating
end
```

Thats where I got stuck, how do I save those values in the record of the @biz.id?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just update the `@biz` object once you find or create it:

```
def update
  @biz = Business.find_or_create_by_name(params[:user][:company_name])
  @biz.update_attributes(params[:businesses])
end
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like its updating the existing business. Its updating the "new" record that was created

Comment: It's going to update whatever is in the `@biz` variable.  If there is no `Business` with a `name` field that matches `params[:user][:company_name]` then it will create a new `Business` instance with `name = params[:user][:company_name]` and then update that.